# WCF - XSD cannot be displayed, when clicking on its link in WSDL

Tags: wcf, iis, xsd, wsdl

I have a WCF service that works fine on my local computer (hosted in IIS, WIN7). Accessing the service via browser and displaying the WSDL and the included XSDs is no problem.
Migrating the service to a server has the effect that the WSDL is still displayed correctly, but the XSDs are not reachable.
The service itself does work, so this one is ok and somehow mysterious to me.

So what might be the reason for not displaying the XSD? (It's a Win Server 2008 and the WS is hosted in IIS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm somehow found the answer on how to solve my problem by myself. I changed the Identity of my ApplicationPool from **ApplicationPoolIdentity to LocalSystem**. Now it's displaying the XSD without any problem. So it seems that there was a problem with the rights the ApplicationPoolIdentity has, this [link](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/620108-problem-wcf-webservice-hosted-iis-6-0-a) pointed me to the right direction.